# Using slice operator [:] on python string do not cause Out of Bound error

Tags: python, string

I have just started learning python and I was playing with the slice (:) operator and strings. For some reason if I specify an invalid index followed by the slice operator it does not give the "Out of range" error.

```
>>> s='Hello'
>>> print s[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range

>>> print s[5:]
//Prints just a newline, no error
```

Can someone please explain why I am not getting error in the 2nd case.

Comment: Nope, slicing never causes out-of-bound exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation on [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

> Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too large is replaced by the string size, an upper bound smaller than the lower bound returns an empty string.

In other words: the index can be too big but in that case it's replaced by the string size.

Note that your string `s` has five characters so `s[5:]` is the same as calling `s[len(s):]` which is the same as getting an empty string (as the missing upper bound defaults to `len(s)` as well, so it ultimately becomes `s[len(s):len(s)]`).