# Slicing n points or as many as possible from list

Tags: python, slice

I'm using python slicing to take elements from a list but don't know if there are going to be enough in there.

At the moment I'm doing this, which feels ugly:

```
        if index + num_to_take > len(values):
            bit = values[index: ]
        else:
            bit = values[index:index + num_to_take]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Just use `bit = values[index:index + num_to_take]` by itself. It will default to `values[index: ]` if there aren't enough numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the `if` condition altogether.

`bit = values[index:index + num_to_take]` would run just fine.

Taking advantage of how slicing works in python. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913529/8293309) for more information.

Comment: Accepted. you answered too fast for me to accept it when I first read it!

Comment: Ohhh... Thanx ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of ifs

`bit = values[index:index + num_to_take]` will run fine